# Automated test with Ruby: select an option from drop-down list

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium

I write automated test with Ruby(Selenium framework) and I need to know how can I select an option from drop-down list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

building on [floehopper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535880/automated-test-with-ruby-select-an-option-from-drop-down-list/538254#538254):

```
selenium.addSelection(locator, value)
or
selenium.select(locator, value)
```

You almost certainly want "id=my_select_box_id" (with the quotes) for `locator`, though other CSS selectors will work.  `value` is the literal text value (not the display value) of the `option` to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are writing a functional test here. Selecting it probably won't do you much good on its own. You need to submit the form in order to test the controller. :)
It might help people answering to know which testing framework you are using, because there are several to choose from.
If you are using RSpec, [check out this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec).

Hope that helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from functional tests, if you're looking for something that acts a bit more like the real app, have a look at [WebRat](http://github.com/brynary/webrat/tree/master).  For non-AJAXed integration tests, it has a very nice DSL for selection your DOMs and taking appropriate actions against them.  (link-clicking form-filling etc.).

On the other hand if your App is an external Web App that you just want to do acceptance tests on, you can also check [Selenimum](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Watir](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/).

Note that WeRat is heavily web framework based where as Selenimum and Watir use the browser to interact with your web app directly (like a real user).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this command :-

```
select(selectLocator, optionLocator)
```

- selectLocator identifies the drop down list
- optionLocator identifies the option within the list

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way of doing this: `select(selectLocator,optionLocator)` as suggested above.

`selectLocator`: name or xpath for dropdown object
`optionLocator`: name or xpath for dropdown option to be selected

E.g.

```
@selenium.select "Language", "label=Ruby"
```